# Problem selecting in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Is it normal to have to select in object mode before moving into edit mode. At the moment if i have not selected something in object mode and i go to edit mode i can not select it. I have tried to save it to help but this makes no difference,

Comment: How can you even enter *Edit Mode* if nothing is selected?

Comment: yes it's normal, you have to choose what object you want to edit

Comment: as they said above, try posting some images so we can understand it better

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is normal. If you don't select an object you won't be able to enter its edit mode. You'll enter the edit mode of the object you've selected. In the 2.80 you'll be able to be in multiple edit modes at once, which is amazing. Try it out! NB: You still need to select objects you want to enter the edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check **Enter Edit Mode** under New Objects in the Editing tab of the User Prefs. It moves the object added to the edit mode and selects it. And when you go back to the object mode it's selected too. NB: For its effective use you add and model your next object **after** you finished previous one.

Answer (score -1):

This was similar to mine..
I noticed that if you *Delete* the Object in **Edit Mode** Like Select all faces and delete them and if you switch to **Object mode** and re-switch it to **Edit mode** without selecting any other object, you will enter into **Edit mode.**
It may be possible that it have an existence as it was not deleted from Object Mode as a **combined** Object.

**Solution is may be you select the object you mentioned and now you can't select that invisible type object so you will not enter edit mode without selecting an Object.**